# PSR-4 autoloading and namespace import not finding classes

Tags: php, namespaces, phpunit, psr-4

I am trying to autoload the contents of `src` folder and `use` them in some unit tests .
Here is the autoloading part of `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "Meetup\\Login\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

There is a class called `users` in `src/core` folder. Screenshot attached.

Any idea why i get the error `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Meetup\Login\Core\Users` in a unit test which tries to import the `users` class using `use Meetup\Login\Core\Users`

[image]
Note: Most probably a stupid oversight from my part.

Comment: I believe the issue is that your class file is users.php while it should be Users.php

Comment: The title of your question is about PSR-4, but in your json stands PSR-0? Also wouldn't [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) look up for the class in `meetup/vendor`?

Comment: Damn! Thanks for the 2nd set of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Orangepill and @Havelock, i indeed have a problem with my eyes.

It should be `psr-4` instead of `psr-0` and `users.php` needs to be renamed as `Users.php`.